# mysql_result resulting error in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, phpmyadmin

I am just shifting my database from MS-Access to mysql

I am using the following code (part of related code only) to retrieve data from mysql

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc","abc@123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }


  $conn= mysql_select_db('xyz', $con);
if (!$con) {
    die ('Can\'t connect to database : ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM Inventory where Text5='y' OR Text5='Y'  ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$rs)
  {exit("Error connecting database,,,");}

while (mysql_fetch_row($rs))
//while (!$rs->EOF)
  {
        $ASIN=trim(mysql_result($rs,"ASIN"));

        $LocalSKU = trim(mysql_result($rs,"LocalSKU"));

        //$ASIN=trim($rs->fields[120]);
        if(trim($ASIN)!=""){
            //include('funtions.php');
            $shipArray = shipingPrice($ASIN);
            $Price=round((mysql_result($rs,"Price")),2);
            $Price2=round((mysql_result($rs,"Price2")),2);
```

but when I run the script I get the following error message

> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
>   in C:\wamp1\www\nathan\amazonPrice.php on line 67

basically, from the query result, I want to select the value of `ASIN` and `LocalSKU` fields to process it further..

can somebody suggest me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions - it is deprecated and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Your problem is right here: mysql_result($rs,"Price").  That function takes three parameters: recordset, row number, and field name/number.

Comment: @alfasin can you suggest how can I replace these sql functions with SQLi?

Comment: @NewBee Marc answered in a comment below

Comment: @alfasin Saying that functions are vulnerable to SQL injection and switching to PDO and mysqli will help is wrong. **Parameterized statements** - this is what protects your from SQL injection.

Comment: @hookman what I'm saying is not wrong (PDO and MySQLi support bindParam() which helps you avoid sql-injection). That said, I agree with your comment that using PDO/MySQLi incorrectly - we'll still be vulnerable to sql-injection and that we should encourage the use of **Prepared statements** (not Parameterized statements).

Comment: There's no excuse for not using placeholders, and you better have a *very* good excuse for using `mysql_query` in 2012. If you're learning how to use MySQL, use PDO or `mysqli`. [Several examples](http://bobby-tables.com/php) show various ways of doing this properly. If you learn the correct techniques now, you won't have to go back and fix the terrible mess you've made.

Comment: @tadman +1 for you, for this great suggession and make me help in learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/mysql_result

The second parameter of mysql_result is the row you want. It's **NOT** a string field.

Your code is rather horrible. You could vastly simplify it with:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$price = $row['price'];
$pric2 = $row['price2'];
etc...
```

Comment: can you suggest how can I replace these sql functions with SQLi?

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli. The function interface to mysqli is very similar to plain old mysql.